# i have my cpanel login of my website. how can i change hosting through cpanel?

Tags: wordpress, hosting, cpanel

I only have the cPanel login of my website. I want to move my website hosting to another hosting platform? how can I do it from cPanel settings?

I tried everything. I don't need the site data so it can be terminated since I need a new site from zero. I have tried all the solutions but nothing seems to work

can someone guide me how to change it? because I have asked all the hosting providers.

Comment: Where is your domain registered?  What are your DNS records (especially NS records)?  Where are you trying to move your hosting?   What specifically have you tried?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.